# I can’t export the mosaic to Google Drive, it is exported in parts and weighs a lot

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2, mosaic

[image]

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
  .filterDate('2022-07-01','2022-08-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry2) ;


print(collection) ;
Map.centerObject(geometry2, 13);
var medianpixels = collection.median(); // This finds the median value of all the pixels which meet the criteria. 

var medianpixelsclipped = medianpixels.clip(geometry2).divide(10000);
// Now visualise the mosaic as a natural colour image. 
Map.addLayer(medianpixelsclipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 1, gamma: 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic',false);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: medianpixelsclipped.select(['B4','B3','B2']),
  description: 'myMosaic',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  region: geometry2,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326' // or the one you prefer
});
```

Comment: According to Google Earth Engine (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#large-file-exports), if the image is too large it will be exported as multiple tiles. You can mosaic them using a GIS software (e.g., QGIS) or in R. Also, it would be nice to share your study area as well and clarify what do you mean by _weighs a lot_.

Comment: Hello! The pictures weigh a lot, some of them were uploaded to Google Drive and I tried to open them in arcmap, but they are completely black, although I kind of exported them to rgb

Comment: _weighs a lot_ means giga byte of storage? If so, try to use a smaller study area. Also, expand your question and include which band(s) you try to export.